# Conver to ISO week to month date on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, iso, week-number

I've searched on almost every question but haven't come with what I need, so here it goes:

I need to convert a date in the format of 'yyyyww' (where 'ww' is the iso week of the year) to 'yyyymm' (where 'mm' is the month of the year).

So, for example, I have the date 201725 (which is year 2017, ISO week 25) to be displayed as 201706, since the ISO week 25 is on June of the same year.

Comment: Why do you want 201706? There are several weeks in June?

Comment: Basically, I want to 'group' the ISO weeks into months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of the `LEFT`, `CONVERT` & `DATEADD` Functions.

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(week, yourfield % 100 - 1, DATEADD(year, yourfield / 100 - 1900, 0)),112),6)
FROM yourtable
```

Input

```
201722
201733
201725
```

Output

```
201705
201708
201706
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00eaa/7/0

Comment: This is the best approach and the most elegant way I've seen!! Thanks for sharing and saving from tons of unnecessary code!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit strange for output because you can get the same value for more than 1 week but I will leave that up to you to sort out.

This produces the desired output stated for the input provided.

```
declare @YourValue varchar(10) = '201725'

select left(replace(convert(varchar(10), dateadd(week, convert(int, right(@YourValue, 2)), left(@YourValue, 4) + '0101'), 102), '.', ''), 6)
```